# Using global dictionary seems bad, but why exactly?

Tags: python

I know in my gut this is **bad**, I just can't put my finger on exactly why.

```
variable = globals()['__builtins__'][sys.argv[1]]
```

For my project I'll be implementing a dictionary that will get the class name I need from command line, so I can limit and control valid input. But I wrote that initially and then was like wait, that's bad. I just can't put words to exactly why.

Is anyone aware of an article or previously answered question that might address this?

Comment: There are more direct ways of getting what you want, for one. `getattr(__builtins__, sys.argv[1])` would do the same thing..

Comment: For one thing, because you're always accessing the same key of `globals`, and you know what this key is when writing the code, it only makes sense to just write `__builtins__` instead of `globals()['__builtins__']` in the first place.  For another thing, none of the versions of Python I have access to even allow you to do `__builtins__[foo]` anyway; did you even get this code to run?

Comment: @jwodder: `__builtins__` (if it is available in the current module namespace) [can be either `__builtin__` module (`builtins` module on Python 3) or its `.__dict__` (the latter has `[]` support)](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/gists/5557682/show_builtins_type.py/python2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to do input sanitization anyway, it could also be written as:

```
ALLOWED_ARGS = {"repr", "str", "unicode"}
funcs = {f: getattr(__builtins__, f) for f in ALLOWED_ARGS}
# funcs.update({"custom": custom_func})

# I'd also assert on all functions having the same arity,
# but this is tricky with builtins...

func = funcs[sys.argv[1]]
```

Not sure why, but seems somehow safer to me.

If you're positive, input is always correct, your code seems fine to me, except that `__builtins__[name]` shouldn't work and you have to use `getattr(__builtins__, name)`.